# Dynamic workflow: storing data in static tables vs creating dynamic table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, workflow, data-modeling

I have an web application where user can create data forms on the fly. The application is in ASP.NET with MSSQL in the backend. In order to create a form, user has to specify fields for a form. In order to add a field, user has to specify field label, type of the field e.g. (numeric, amount, email ) and other attributes. Below is an example of a dynamic form configuration

**Form Name:** Sales

**Field Label**: Customer Name
**Field Type**: text
**Length**: 100

**Field Label**: Amount
**Field Type**: money

I hope you are getting the gist. There can be many such forms. There can be thousands of rows for each form. The field configuration is stored in tables with schema as below:

**Table:** DataTypes
**Column:** DataTypeId int, DataTypeName varchar(100)

**Table:** FormFields
**Columns:** FieldId int, FieldLabel varchar(100), DataTypeId int

There are two ways I can store the form values in database.

**Approach 1:** Store data in static tables as a key value pair. With this approach my table will look like below:

**Table:** FormFieldValues
**Columns:** FieldId int, Numeric_value numeric(18,5), Text_Value varchar(500), Money_Value money

So a row in FormFieldValues table will look like below

Field Id |  Numeric_Value | Text_Value | Money_Value

1            100.512
2                            John Wayne

3                                         $200.50

The advantage of this approach is that since the table structure is static, dynamic SQL is not needed when fetching rows for example. The disadvantage is to convert rows into columns in code.

**Approach 2**: Using the fields configuration, create a dynamic table on the fly. So in above example I can create a table as below

**Table:** Form1
**Columns**: Id int, CustomerName varchar(100), Amount money, Version numeric (15,5)

A row in this table looks like this

CustomerName |  Amount |    Version

John Wayne      $200.50      100.512

Advantage of this approach, each column is created accordingly to exact precision specified in the field configuration. Disadvantage is dynamic SQL is needed to fetch the data and store it.

Which approach is better approach ? Which approach would be more scalable and performance friendly in the long run?

Note: SO doesn't support table formats so the tables may not appear proper but I hope the readers will get the gist

Comment: did you find any solution/ other methods that will help in this ? could you please share your answer @devanalyst

Comment: No. But I have decided to go with Approach 1